# Replace new line from the end of string SQL and update columns

Tags: sqlite

I have a table called **Players** with two columns **Name** and **PlayerID**. I am using **SQLite** under *DB Browser for SQLite*.

Unfortunately, all my player's names have a something like a "\n" (a newline) at the end of their **Name**.

Ex:

```
"Mark
"
```

I tried to use Update & Replace for all the names with the following query (I have like 450 rows in the table):

```
UPDATE Players
SET Name = REPLACE(Name,CHAR(10),'')
WHERE PlayerID <= 500
```

When I execute something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Players
WHERE Players.Name LIKE 'Mark'
```

it'll return no rows because of the end line. Here 'Mark' has no "\n", so it won't be found.

If I execute:

```
SELECT * FROM Players
WHERE Players.Name LIKE 'Mark
'
```

it will return my player. (after Mark I pressed enter)

I want to change all my rows from this format

```
"Mark
"
```

to this

```
"Mark"
```

and save all the changes.

How can I solve my problem? What's wrong?

Comment: The new line character is usually represented as `\n`, but sometimes, `\r\n` may be used so use those instead of the empty `''` in your replace line

Comment: @CoolGuyCG I want to remove the new line added at the end of all the names. From what I found on the internet, CHAR(10) is that new line and I want to remove it so  I used ''. I think I'm missing something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

The problem was that I had `/r` at the end of each string, not `\n`. So I had to use CHAR(13) instead of CHAR(10).

```
UPDATE Players
SET Name = REPLACE(Name, CHAR(13), '')
```

Also to remove **all** line feed characters (`\n`) I used:

```
UPDATE Players
SET Name = REPLACE(Name, CHAR(10), '')
```

Moreover to remove **all** the spaces () I used:

```
UPDATE Players
SET Name = REPLACE(Name, ' ', '')
```